# Link to ntdll.lib and call functions inside ntdll.dll

Tags: c, visual-studio, dll, window

I'm recently doing some research on private APIs. I tried to call functions such as `NtOpenFile` in ntdll.dll with `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` at runtime. Luckly, it succeed. This morning I performed a file search on my computer and find `ntdll.lib` in my C drive. As far as I know of, such .lib file should contain stubs for dll exports available for linking. So, I tried to link my application to that lib but I'm constantly getting `unresolved external symbol` errors.  However, a `dumpbin /EXPORTS` shows that ntdll.lib clearly has NtOpenFile exported. How could I resolve this error?

Comment: You cannot statically link to NtDll. You are already doing it the right way, calling `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress`.

Comment: But what's the point of `ntdll.ib` ? If we can't statically link to it, why is it there?

Comment: The lib can be linked but you then you must have a header file that give you all function definitions.

Comment: The problem is, VS and CodeBlock are yelling at me saying can't find the NtOpenFile symbol. @LPs

Comment: Wrong, there are ntdll import libraries (with complete headers) available now.  
True for the default setup Windows SDK yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the name of the function as recorded in the library and as it is generated from compiler.
`dumpbin` just shows you the base exported symbol `NtOpenFile` (the undecorated one), but there is also a import symbol `__imp_NtOpenFile`.
Now if you try to link statically `NtOpenFile` declaring it as:

```
NTSTATUS NtOpenFile(
  _Out_ PHANDLE            FileHandle,
  _In_  ACCESS_MASK        DesiredAccess,
  _In_  POBJECT_ATTRIBUTES ObjectAttributes,
  _Out_ PIO_STATUS_BLOCK   IoStatusBlock,
  _In_  ULONG              ShareAccess,
  _In_  ULONG              OpenOptions
);
```

The compiler will generate, for a `__stdcall` function under 32bits, the symbol `_NtOpenFile@24`, if I'm not wrong counting the bytes size of call arguments, that obviously is not in the library.
This is due to the fact that ntdll.lib is intended to be used under DDK for drivers development, where the compiler generates undecorated symbols.
To clarify the concept open the ntdll.lib file with a binary editor and look for `NtOpenFile`, you will see only it and the import version `__imp_NtOpenFile`. Now open a standar library as gdi32.lib, just to name one, and search for `CreateDIBSection` you'll find a `_CreateDIBSection@24` and also `__imp__CreateDIBSection@24`.
So what's going on? Simple dumpbin shows always the undecorated names, but the compiler generates decorated ones, result: the linker fails. It is said that names use `PASCAL` convention, that is the same as `__stdcall`, but doesn't decorate symbols (i.e. read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa235591(v=vs.60).aspx).
There is a way to solve the problem? Yes you have to create your own import library assigning an alias to the wanted function having the correct decorations. Start reading this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b9xe492.aspx.

Comment: This describes the process necessary to make calls into NTdll directly. As he said you can make a typedef alias for the function call represented by a pointer to an address which you obtain using GetProcAddress called on the LoadLibrary function.
http://resources.infosecinstitute.com/calling-ntdll-functions-directly/#gref

Comment: This is no longer the case with VS2017.
It might take the WDK, but it has a "ntdll.lib" that you can use from user mode Desktop programs.

Answer (score 10):

No longer the case, you can find ntdll.lib import library and NT headers as I write this in 2019.

It's a lot of extra code to do it the *GetProcAddress()* way. Certainly direct imports is cleaner and is the pattern we're used to for C/C++ desktop applications.

I used to make my own "ntdll.lib" import library by creating a simple Windows DLL project with a .def file, etc. Adding each ntdll API function one at the time as I needed them as a stub and for a header file.
Throwing away the .dll, just using the .lib from it.

But at least since MSVC 2017 it includes user mode (for desktop applications) ntdll.lib libraries for x86 and ARM in both 32bit and 64bit varieties. This might require the Windows 10 WDK to be installed.
Just search your "C:\Program Files (x86)" for "ntdll.lib" and you should find them.

Then on the header front, a lot of the ntdll prototypes and definitions are in "winternl.h" but unfortunately many parts are missing and/or there are only simplified versions of structures, etc.
To solve this you can use the fantastic NT header set from the "Process Hacker" project:
https://github.com/processhacker/processhacker
The headers are in "phnt".

Instead of the typical "windows.h" and "winternl.h" combo, you will use:

```
#include <phnt_windows.h>
#include <phnt.h>
```

And then to specificity Windows 10 as a target for example (default is Windows 7) you would follow that with:

```
#undef PHNT_VERSION
#define PHNT_VERSION PHNT_THRESHOLD
```

Note "phnt_windows.h" already includes "windows.h" for you.
So you should be able to follow it with any other Windows, stdlib, stl, etc., headers after; not much different then the typical desktop build environment.

Or some others to use:
https://github.com/Fyyre/ntdll
Also includes libs:
https://github.com/x64dbg/ScyllaHide/tree/master/3rdparty/ntdll
Yet another with ntdll libraries too:
https://github.com/odzhan/injection/tree/master/ntlib