# Is it good to use ntdll.dll in a win32 console application?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, file-io

Short: 
In my c++ project i need to read/write extended file properties. I managed it with using alternate data streams (ADS). My problem is, for opening the ADS i need to use the `CreateFile` API. But it is not fulfilling my needs. NtCreateFile will fullfill all my needs. (Or alternatively `NtSetEaFile` and `NtQueryEaFile`) But `NtCreateFile` is not directly accessible from a win32 console application.

I know i can use this function easily via `GetProcAdres`s. But i like to know the opinion of you all, if i did miss something? Some other libs are using this pattern already, for example Chromium (https://github.com/chromium-googlesource-mirror/chromium/blob/1c1996b75d3611f56d14e2b30e7ae4eabc101486/src/sandbox/src/win_utils.cc function: `ResolveNTFunctionPtr`)
But im uncertain, because the c++ project is not a hobby project and i ask myself if it is dangerous or not.

I guess `NtCreateFile` is maybe the securest way to do, because it is well documented and supported by `winternl.h` header. Especially because this method is unchanged since windows 2000. But what is with `NtSetEaFile`, `NtQueryEaFile` which are fitting my needs perfectly. They are only half documented. A documentation for `ZwSetEaFile` and `ZwQueryEaFile` exist (unchanged since windows 2000).

Reason why i want to do that:

I want to write and read extended properties from files via ADS. But in case of writing the extended property of a given file the first time, i need to open the file with `OPEN_ALWAYS`. In case of file is not existing it will create a new file, even if i only access not the content stream of the file. To avoid this i get first the handle of the original file and check with this HANDLE if the file still exist.
But i dont want to blog any file with reduced access rights, because from my point of view that is a very bad pattern. The user needs to have full access to any file any time. Because of that we open all HANDLES with the flag `FILE_SHARE_DELETE` | `FILE_SHARE_READ` | `FILE_SHARE_WRITE`. And now i have the race.

```
auto hFile = CreateFileW(originalPath, …, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, …).
// this is the little race: if somebody at least rename originalPath the
// second CreateFileW call will cause the creation of a empty file with the
// path originalPath (the old path).
auto hADS = CreateFileW(originalPath + adsName, …, FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, OPEN_ALWAYS, …).
```

This is a main issue, especially because this happens from time to time in our tests. `NtCreateFile` will fix it, because i can create the second `HANDLE` with the help of the first `HANDLE`. Because of that no race. Or `NtSetEaFile` and `NtQueryEaFile` will help, because i only need one HANDLE.

The thing is, that the application needs not to be save for the future, because ADS works only on `NTFS` anyway. And who knows when `NTFS` will be exchanged. But i dont want a flaky behaviour. I want to trust this Methods. I I am fine if the API will change in the future and the software needs to adapt to it. But i want to be sure, that all Windows higher or equal then 7 can deal with it. Somebody some experience to share? I would like to hear them very much.

Comment: *But NtCreateFile is not directly accessible from a win32 console application* this is not true. it accessible in same way like say `CreateFile`. simply link with *ntdll[p].lib*. console or not console not play any role. and *ADS != EA*, you all time confuse it. you want use *EA* how i understand

Comment: *A documentation for ZwSetEaFile and ZwQueryEaFile exist* yes. and in user mode   *NtXxx == ZwXxx* both names point to the same function

Comment: @RbMm Thx for your awnser. I am not confused with ADS and EA. But both concepts are fulfilling my needs. Because with ADS I try to copy the behaviour of EA. Are you sure with linking against ntdll[p].lib. And can I access with that lib even NtSetEaFile?

Comment: I not figured out yet, how to link against the lib. Because I thought the concept of ntdll.dll is, that it can change from release to release including the api. And because of that I am not able to link static against it. You know some example projects? I could not find any of them, which looks solid for me. So if I compile against the newest WDK the lib does not contain only a reference to the address of the dll, what I read on another side? And because WDK guarantee to work with WIndows 7-10, I am save?

Comment: *Are you sure with linking against ntdll[p].lib. And can I access with that lib even NtSetEaFile?* - yes. i do this my self. so 100% sure and know this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35509388/link-to-ntdll-lib-and-call-functions-inside-ntdll-dll I was referencing to this question, where somebody was saying GetProcAdress is best practice. But I was reading it now again and if I understand it right, I just have to declare a own header file for the lib and then access everything.But I am very suspicious. Because the lib has only the size of 472-827 KB. I guess the difference between ntdll.lib and ntdllp.lib is that second one contains more functions. But how Microsoft can change the Api from version to version if I link like that against it

Comment: *I am not able to link static against it.* - this is false. you can link with it. absolute the same way like you link with *kernel32.lib*, *user32.lib*, etc.

Comment: again - use *ntdll.lib* (or *ntdllp.lib*) in same way like you use any another lib. simply open linker property pages, and in input, additional dependencies - add *ntdll.lib*. from which wdk version you get this lib - not play any role, because all this api exist already in win2000 - so any *ntdll.lib* is ok for you

Comment: *I just have to declare a own header file for the lib and then access everything.* - you can and use wdk headers as well, for not copy-paste declarations yourself ([*example*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48987318/6401656) - the *ntdllp.lib* containing more api definitions compare *ntdll.lib* and main - it containing some static linked functions - it useful if we not use crt. but if use - it may conflict with it. *But how Microsoft can change the Api from version to version if I link like that against it* - but not such api like `NtCreateFile`.

Comment: *where somebody was saying GetProcAdress is best practice* - but how you can call `GetProcAdress` ? without first get address of this api with.. `GetProcAdress` ?! exactly how you can call `GetProcAdress` you can call say `ZwQueryEaFile`. (and you use *kernel32.lib* from which sdk version ?) so really no any problems here at all. link with *ntdll[p].lib* and call api from it as any another api

Comment: This is not real question. RbMm have true, I dont see problem with linking ntdll.lib.

Comment: Okay, but I assume Microsoft is changing the API methods in windows next version, why ever. In this case my software will crash without any warnings when it runs under newest windows. If I link dynamically the program can react to this issue and handle it gracefully. But you all think it will not changed, because WDK of Windows ensure, that it is compatible to Windows 7-10 and believe it will be compatible to newer version as well.

Comment: Okay, but I assume Microsoft is changing the API methods in windows next version - what if changed ordinal number, function name or remove completly? GetProcAddress fail too. No sense to your question.

Comment: @user2120666 Of course GetProcAdress will fail, but you can handle it, during execution. In the other way your software will just crash.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Why this is a XY Problem. At the moment nobody was really answering my question. The first big answer is wrong. And I described the original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not really unsecure to use this kind of APIs if their is a documentation. In case of `NtSetEaFile`, `NtQueryEaFile` and `NtCreateFile` you can find a description inside of Microsoft's Doc. (keep in mind NtXxx == ZwXxx)

But this API can change in the future and Microsoft does not guarantee that it will provides the same methods in the next Windows version. If you can, use the public API, because then you are safe. If not it is a case by case decision. In this case the three methods from the API are unchanged since Windows2000. Plus for example `NtSetEaFile` and `NtQueryEaFile` is used by Microsoft for WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux). And especially `NtCreateFile` is used by a wide range of OpenSource Projects. So it is very unlikely that this API will change.

In my use case another aspect is important. Because I wanted to use ADS, but ADS is only supported by NTFS. So using ADS does not ensure future compatibility as well. So it was very clear for me using `NtSetEaFile` and `NtQueryEaFile`.

But how you can use this kind of APIs? Dynamic or static linking is possible. It depends on your needs what is better. In case of static linking you need to download the last WDK (Windows Driver Kit) and link against the ntdll.lib. In case of dynamic linking you can access the dll directly via `GetModuleHandle` and finding out the address of the method with `GetProcAddress`. Under Windows `ntdll.dll` is accessible from any application. In both cases you don't have directly a header file. You have to define the header file by yourself or use WDK to get them.

In my project dynamic linking was the best choice. The reason was, that on every windows the right implementation will be choosen and in case the method is not available i have the chance to deactivate the feature in my software instead of crash. Microsoft is recommending the dynamic way, because of the last reason.

Simple PseudoCode (dynamic case):

```
typedef struct _FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION {
    ULONG  NextEntryOffset;
    UCHAR  Flags;
    UCHAR  EaNameLength;
    USHORT EaValueLength;
    CHAR   EaName[1];
} FILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION, *PFILE_FULL_EA_INFORMATION;

typedef struct _IO_STATUS_BLOCK {
    union {
        NTSTATUS Status;
        PVOID    Pointer;
    };
    ULONG_PTR Information;
} IO_STATUS_BLOCK, *PIO_STATUS_BLOCK;

typedef NTSTATUS(WINAPI *NtSetEaFileFunction)(IN HANDLE FileHandle,
                                              OUT       PIO_STATUS_BLOCK
                                                        IoStatusBlock,
                                              IN PVOID Buffer,
                                              IN ULONG Length);

HMODULE  ntdll                   = GetModuleHandle(L"ntdll.dll");
NtSetEaFileFunction function     = nullptr;
FARPROC *function_ptr            = reinterpret_cast<FARPROC *>(&function);

*function_ptr = GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtQueryEaFile");

// function could be used normally.
```

The other answer is incorrect. The reason is that the reason of my problem is, that I need to use `OPEN_ALWAYS`. Of course, if you don't need this flag, everything is fine. But in my case there is a point where I needed to create the ADS. And it will not be created without the `OPEN_ALWAYS` flag.

Comment: DLL's are *always* dynamically linked. You are referring to [run-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/run-time-dynamic-linking) (as opposed to [load-time dynamic linking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/load-time-dynamic-linking)).

Answer (score 3):

This question is wrong. Your proposed solution for your problem, is not using NtCreateFile, but use CreateFile with dwCreationDisposition set to the OPEN_EXISTING.

From [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea):

> OPEN_EXISTING
>
> Opens a file or device, only if it exists. If the specified file or
> device does not exist, the function fails and the last-error code is
> set to ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

Simply open file if exists and set whatever you want. If file is renamed, CreateFile returns ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND.

**THE PROBLEM**

*Now, to your proposed solution, what is better method or why is not possible use ntdll.dll in win32 console application (???).
Again, your "better" method - GetProcAddress is "wrong" same as using linking against ntdll.dll. In **Windows 11**, or **Windows 12** or **Windows 3030** the function may be removed and both solutions (statical vs. dynamical import) will be fail.*

Comment: What i learned from investigating is,it is not wrong to use ntdll.dll in win32 console application. But if you use them, it is possible that in future methods of the api disappear or change.Now their are two option you have. Link static against ntdll.lib. In this case it will work at lest for each version supported by the used WDK. But  in future your software could crash if the used API changed. Or you link dynamically. In this case the software has the chance to react to this issue and inform the user. Because of that Microsoft suggest second way. So i disagree with your formulation "wrong".

Comment: your awnser is **WRONG**. Because how can I create a alternate data stream, if I not create it with OPEN_ALWAYS. So pls, why this have three upvotes and I getting 3 down votes. Really, why? This awnser is not hitting my question. First I thought he was right, but I compiled the wrong code. But if I change OPEN_ALWAYS to OPEN_ESISTING, I can not create a ADS. (of course I know that) So pls. ...